# Does the Apple AirPort Extreme A1521 have a time capsule in it?

Tags: time-machine, airport, time-capsule

I have received one of these to sell and I'm finding conflicting information as to whether this unit has a time capsule in it.

I am unfamiliar with Apple products and need to wipe any data on this if it contains personal information.

Is this just a wireless router or does it contain a hard drive with Time Capsule data?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, just a regular AirPort Extreme. Not a Time Capsule model.

They look identical but if you take it apart you will find they both have a cavity where a HDD would sit but the A1521 lacks a logic board SATA cable and power connection while the Time Capsule model includes it.

[image: Airport Extreme]
[image: Time Capsule]

Comment: Is the model number different on the underside of the Time Capsule variant?

Comment: Yes it is different